# Can we cancel flags?

Tags: support, flagging, exact-duplicates

Is it possible to cancel a flag. In case it isn't possible, is it possible to change the link to the original post for the duplicate flag?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is not possible at present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/251274). Suggestion: add a comment with a link to better duplicate (or with a reason why your flag should be ignored), so that others will  see it when voting on the question.